# Laravel hasManyThrough, with belongs to between the other two models

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

Not sure how clear is the question title, I will try to elaborate:

**Tables:**

repairs (Model: Repair):

```
id
id_supplier
id_store
```

suppliers (Model: Supplier):

```
id
```

store (Model: Store):

```
id
```

**Relations:**

Repair:

```
public function supplier() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier', 'id_supplier');
}
```

Supplier:

```
public function repairs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Repair', 'id_supplier');
}
```

Store:

```
public function repairs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Repair', 'id_store');
}
```

What i need from here is to get the collection of all suppliers a given store worked with, through the repairs that were made there, so my first thought it was [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), but no ideia what to pass as 4º parameter:

Store:

```
public function suppliers() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Supplier', 'App\Repair', 'id_supplier', '<NO IDEIA WHAT'S HERE>');
}
```

What am I missing? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use HasManyThrough here. Try something like this in your code:

```
$store = Store::with('repairs.supplier')->find($id_store);//eager load
$repairs = $store->repairs->pluck('supplier');//get array of suppliers id
$suppliers = (new Collection($repairs))->unique();//get unique collection of suppliers (without duplicates)
```

where `$id_store` is id of store which suppliers you want to get

Comment: Try it in controller, not in model

Comment: It's increase performance - you get all relations in one request

Comment: Pluck - is making array, and then we create a collection with this array

Comment: About relation - you may use foreach with suppliers and get relations you need; About parantheses - try it with, and without

Comment: Just discovered that `return $this->repairs->pluck('supplier')->unique();` was enought on the stores model, `suppliers()` method, didn't know about https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck method